# Как изменить старый коммит?

Tags: git, github

Осваиваю git, работая над приложением.
На данный момент у меня есть ветка мастер и еще одна ветка - hotfix.
Работая в ветке hotfix, я заметил, что в одном из предыдущих коммитов я забыл добавить некоторые данные в один из файлов.
Можно, конечно, добавить их сейчас, и просто сделать коммит с этими изменениями, но в целях изучения, я хотел бы изменить старый коммит, в котором был добавлен этот файл.
Конечная цель:

1. изменен файл, который был добавлен в старом коммите
2. этот файл, в измененном виде, добавлен в этот старый коммит
3. во всех последующих коммитах в этой ветке, видны изменения
4. сделан пуш в github

Как правильно работать в такой ситуации?

Comment: для этого есть git rebase. Но некоторые его сильно не любят.

Comment: есть замечательное руководство по Git в котором освещаются все аспекты его работы, оно есть на русском, конретные шаги дял решения вашей проблемы описаны тут https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: спасибо, я что-то выпустил из виду, что есть русские руководства. это именно то, что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Для изменение НЕ последнего коммита выполните:

```
git rebase --interactive
```

[Источник](https://habr.com/ru/post/201922/).